# Process.Start with md5 hash as argument

Tags: c#, arguments, md5, process.start

I need the MD5 hash to be the second argument after "login".

Here is the Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace LauncherBeta1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void maskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var password = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(maskedTextBox1.Text);
            var account = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

            var hmacMD5 = new HMACMD5(password);
            var saltedHash = hmacMD5.ComputeHash(account);

            string[] args = { "login", saltedHash };
            Process.Start("program.exe", String.Join(" ", args));
        }

    }
}
```

The compiler says the line `string[] args = { "login", saltedHash };` has a syntax problem. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: "As you can see" - nope, not really... it would have helped if you'd shown the compiler error. Still...

Comment: we cannot find out anything either, since you do not include the exception details. put a try catch around the method's content and edit your question with the exception type and message or stacktrace.

Comment: @Davide: If there's a syntax error, there can't be an exception, as it can't be running...

Comment: Right, right... so compiler error please...

Comment: What I guess is that var saltedHash = ... does not put a string in "saltedHash"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `ComputeHash` returns a byte array, not a string. You need to convert that byte array into a string somehow. For example, you could use Base64 encoding:

```
string[] args = { "login", Convert.ToBase64String(saltedHash) };
```

But the encoding will need to be whatever the process expects. It may well expect a hex-encoded form instead, e.g.

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(saltedHash).Replace("-", "");
string[] args = { "login", hex };
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet!
Got it to work now~

Edit: I had to convert it to string.